# Is it possible to use PHP as a database call handler for my javafx app?

Tags: java, php, mysql, javafx, database-connection

I have a javafx app that i created and it makes calls to the mysql database. Unfortunately the database username and password is viewable if you view the jar files.  Is there a way to have the javafx app connect to a PHP file on my web host server to manage these database calls and database connection so I do not need to store the creds client side? Or is there a better way to handle this server side? Maybe an API?

[Uploaded picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzOPV.png)

Comment: You can use a server with a REST API, for example, to connect to your database, but if the password is stored on the server, and the server authenticates with the database, how are you going to prevent anyone from connecting to the server? It seems all you've done is shifted the problem. Typically in this scenario, your JavaFX application would prompt the user for the database password (or a password to the server, if you choose to go through a server).

Comment: Well I cant give them the DB password  because then they would have complete access to changing stuff right?

Comment: Your app should connect to the DB with an account that has only the privileges that the app needs. So if the app is allowed to make any changes to the database, then they can already do that via the app, and you lose nothing if they have the password. If the app, e.g., only reads data, then have it connect using an account that only has SELECT privileges.

Comment: This just sounds more like a question about managing MYSQL user accounts, than a question on how to structure your application.

Comment: Just create a read only mysql user for your application, then use those creds inside your app. Just use mySQL workbench or a cPanel or whatever your site uses.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should determine is the data that you want to read/write using your java application. Only that data that it needs.

The second is why do you beware of revealing storage access credentials? Is it because of data that shouldn't be visible from the java application?

If an application has access to data hance the owner of the application has access to data. No other options here. The only thing you can do here is to restrict access for each application to its data. It means that each application should have its own credentials which give access to that application's data.

It doesn't matter if you use either MySQL direct connection or API. In both cases, you have some access credentials (DB login+password or API token) or don't have credentials at all but the last one means everyone will have access.